# ROC curve for perfect labeling is produced upside down by package ROCR

Tags: r, roc

The code

```
library(magrittr)
library(ROCR)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(GermanCredit)

GermanCredit %<>% arrange(Class)
GermanCredit$perfect_prob = sort(runif(nrow(GermanCredit)), decreasing = TRUE)

perf = performance(prediction(GermanCredit$perfect_prob, GermanCredit$Class), "tpr", "fpr")

data.frame(FalsePositive = unlist(perf@x.values),
           TruePositive = unlist(perf@y.values),
           method = rep(names(select(GermanCredit, perfect_prob)),
                        times=c(length(perf@x.values[[1]])))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=FalsePositive, y=TruePositive, color=method)) +
  geom_line()
```

displays the curve

[image]

which is clearly wrong. What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out for the life of me. The target is "Bad". So I made sure that

```
> levels(GermanCredit$Class)
[1] "Bad"  "Good"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While caret considers the first of the levels as the positive class, as seen when using

```
confusionMatrix(..., reference=GermanCredit$Class)
```

ROCR considers the later level to be the positive class. The logic is that `1` is the positive class and `0` the negative and since `0 < 1` and `"Bad" < "Good"`, ROCR considers `"Good"` to be the positive class here.

The solution is to use explicit ordering:

```
pred = prediction(GermanCredit$perfect_prob, GermanCredit$Class, label.ordering = c("Good", "Bad")
perf = performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
```

Now `"Good" < "Bad"` and `"Bad"` is considered to be the positive class by `prediction`.